# Show background image in a div underneath navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

New to bootstrap.

1. I want to show a background image underneath the `NavBar` within a `div` in `bootstrap`. For some reason the image in the code below is not rendering correct height. How do i achieve the correct height whilst at the same time maintaining the responsiveness of the image?
2. Also, how can we change the color of the `NavBar` on scroll? Nothing happens with the code below when I scroll.

Html:

```
          <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-secondary fixed-top text-uppercase" id="mainNav">


        <div class="container">
          <a class="navbar-brand js-scroll-trigger" href="#page-top">  <img src="img/logo-clear.png" alt="logo" style="width:160px;"></a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right text-uppercase bg-primary text-white rounded" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            Menu
            <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
              <li class="nav-item mx-0 mx-lg-1">
                <a class="nav-link py-2 px-0 px-lg-3 rounded js-scroll-trigger" href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item mx-0 mx-lg-1">
                <a class="nav-link py-2 px-0 px-lg-3 rounded js-scroll-trigger" href="#about">About</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item mx-0 mx-lg-1">
                <a class="nav-link py-2 px-0 px-lg-3 rounded js-scroll-trigger" href="#services">Services</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item mx-0 mx-lg-1">
                <a class="nav-link py-2 px-0 px-lg-3 rounded js-scroll-trigger" href="#contact">Contact</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>

  <!-- Header -->
  <div class="page-header bg-primary" style="background-image: url(./img/1.jpg);">
    <p class="text-center text-uppercase text-secondary mb-0" id="mainText">Portfolio</p>
  </div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
/*for navbar*/
.bg-secondary {
  background-color: transparent !important;
    /* background-color: transparent !important; */
}

.bg-secondary.scrolled{
   background-color: #333300 !important;
}

.page-header{
  background-size: cover;
  height: auto;
}
```

JS:

```
 <script>
  $(window).scroll(function(){
    $('nav').toggleClass('scrolled', $(this).scrollTop() > $('nav'));
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/wwWaldi/nrysp61w/10/

You gotta set the height to your header, (i changed the url of the header for demo)

```
height: 300px;
```

Comment: Whenever I add the height, the background image stops being responsive in width. Not sure why.

Comment: That is because the `background-size` is set to cover, it will be responsive up to the height of the element.

Comment: How would you suggest to achieve the responsiveness while at the same time showing the appropriate image height.?

Comment: Maybe add a `background-position: center center;` to it? At some point you'll have to use media queries to change height on different break points  https://jsfiddle.net/wwWaldi/nrysp61w/15/